# Get 2d index from flattened array

Tags: julia

Given the array:

`arr = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6]`

```
3×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4
 5  6
```

which is flattened `flat_arr = collect(Iterators.flatten(arr))`

```
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1                       
 3                       
 5                       
 2                       
 4                       
 6
```

I sometimes need to go between both index formats. For example, if I got the sorted indices of `flat_arr`, I may want to iterate over `arr` using these sorted indices. In Python, this is typically done with [`np.unravel_index`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html). How is this done in Julia? Do I just need to write my own function?

Comment: Note that `flatten` is not really intended to transform arrays to vectors. "Flattening" rather means transforming vectors of vectors to "plain" (non-nested) vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished using `CartesianIndices`.

```
c_i = CartesianIndices(arr)
flat_arr[2] == arr[c_i[2]]) == 3
```

Answer (score 1):

`vec()` creates a 1-d view of the array. Hence you can have both pointers to the array in the memory and use whichever one you need in any minute (they point to the same array):

```
julia> arr = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6]
3×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4
 5  6

julia> arr1d = vec(arr)
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 3
 5
 2
 4
 6

julia> arr1d[4] = 99
99

julia> arr
3×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  99
 3   4
 5   6
```

Note that in Julia arrays are stored in column major order and hence the fourth value is the first value in the second column